# How to set file name in download - suggest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-suggest

I am trying to put a `ON/OFF` button on my Chrome Extension.
This state is saved in local data.
What I want is to get that data and if it is `ON` execute the main code. Else, do nothing.

At first, without the status comprobation it was working. After that, I added the status comprobation and everything is working but the suggest.
It says: `suggest({ filename: newFilename, conflict_action: "uniquify" });`

This is the current code in `background.js`:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
    
    chrome.storage.local.get('status', function(data) { 
        console.log(data)
        console.log(Object.keys(data).length === 0)
        console.log(data.status ==true)
        var isEnabled = false
        if ((Object.keys(data).length === 0) || (data.status ==true)){
            isEnabled = true
        }
        console.log('Estado recuperado:', isEnabled);
        if (isEnabled) {
            var domain = getDomain(item.url);
            if (domain !== null) {
                var newFilename = domain + "/" + item.filename;
                console.log(newFilename)
                suggest({ filename: newFilename, conflict_action: "uniquify" });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The code above is not working; the code below works.

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
    var domain = getDomain(item.url);
    console.log(domain)
    if (domain !== null) {
        var newFilename = domain + "/" + item.filename;
        suggest({ filename: newFilename, conflict_action: "uniquify" });
    } else {
        suggest({}); // No se pudo obtener el dominio, seguir con el nombre original.
    }
});
```

I have used await and asyncronous functions but it is not working. I also tried to obtain the status from another function but with no success.

Comment: I believe it's because there's no else part for this :  'if (domain !== null) '. When the domain is null it does nothing. In the second case though, there's an else condition.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Hello, it's not that... but thank you

Comment: Check where is the getDomain method. My gut feelig is around what is 'this' poiting in the second nested callback.